# Verify a certificate using openssl verify with root CA without crlDistributionPoints

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509certificate

I'm trying to verify a certificate which has the below relation:

`Root Certificate - Intermediate Certificate - User Certificate`

Root Cert is a self signed certificate ***without crlDistributionPoints***, Intermediate Certificate is signed by Root with crlDistributionPoints and User by Intermediate with crlDistributionPoints.

Now I want to verify if a User Certificate has its anchor by Root Certificate.

With

```sh
cat root_ca.pem intermediate_ca.pem > ca_chain.pem

openssl verify -verbose -show_chain -crl_check_all -crl_download -CAfile ca_chain.pem  user_cert.pem
```

Result into :

```
error 3 at 2 depth lookup: unable to get certificate CRL
error user_cert.pem: verification failed
```

It looks like openssl is trying and failing to get CRL for root certificate. Is there a way to not try to get CRL for root certificate only?

If I use `-crl_check` flag then I am only checking CRL against user_cert and not intermediate_ca.

Any suggestions or workaround?

Comment: If you're on Windows, you can use certutil.exe as a workaround to openssl.exe.  For example, `certutil.exe -f -split -urlfetch -verify user_cert.pem`.  This command also downloads all the CRL and OCSP file(s) to the local folder for further inspection.  Worth a mention.

Comment: I am using AWS Lambda with NodeJS on Linux OS

Comment: OK.  Can you add that information to your question and/or add them as tags?